# How do I protect the walls next to a 24 foot tall red brick fireplace when painting it?

Tags: painting, fireplace, preparation

What is the easiest and best way to paint a very tall brick fireplace?  It is 24 feet tall old Chicago (red) style brick.  I would like to use a sprayer but am afraid of the over spray when spraying up on the high area.  I have a very good and long ladder (and a very able bodied husband), although it really scares me to have him up that high! Any advice would be great.

Comment: Overspray can be managed with masking with side kraft paper made explicitly for this purpose. For floors and / or large wall areas you can also use poly plastic that comes on large rolls with the plastic up to 12 feet wide.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Please post answers as answers not as comments.

Comment: You must have a large living room.

Answer (score 5):

It makes me die a little inside when people paint over raw red brick....

That said, you tape and paper the walls where they meet the brick. Then you plastic from the paper as far out as you think you might overspray. You may even want to form a "curtain" out of the plastic to keep the brick in a make-shift paint booth.

It is just as you would mask any other wall, though you will likely need to touch-up the seam where the brick meets the treated wall, it shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 3):

Overspray can be managed with masking on the sides with kraft paper made explicitly for this purpose. For floors and / or large wall areas you can also use poly plastic that comes on large rolls with the plastic up to 12 feet wide